# C#/J# Find function by name / Manual control click

Tags: c#, click, controls, j#

I have a control which is a button and I want to manually click it. (When the user presses a button)

I have the control but I don't know how to get it's function. (The format of the click function is [Control.Name]_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) as usual

Does anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have the button, instead of trying to find the method, I would recommend just calling [Button.PerformClick](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.button.performclick.aspx) instead.  This will trigger *all* of the event handlers on the button's Click event, no matter what name they've been assigned.

Comment: OMG there is actually a function called PerformClick... I actually need to do the same for LinkLabel(Which doesn't have PerformClick) But I'll 'V' you anyway